# How to persist SQLite database on Icenium?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I try to build a database on Icenium with SQLite and the db does not persist - why? I think the structure of the database is not built on a physical level. Someone you ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use SQLite with Icenium on my project successfully. As I see, there is also an example that you can look up:

https://github.com/Icenium/sample-sqlite.git

You might also want to take a look at this post: [Creating a Database from a SQL Dump](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-fourth-day-of-phonegapping-creating.html), for using prepopulated SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Telerik AppBuilder (formerly called Icenium), each time you Run the project in a simulator,  the simulator starts from scratch and it keeps no record of what happened in previous runs.

**The solution I would use to 'persist' the database on  a session basis and test your code is as below.**

```
You must keep the simulator open (so don't close it) to keep database intact
and just press Reload button in simulator window to see how an existing database 
would run on a real device every time the app is re-started on a real device, 
because within a single Run of the simulator it remembers everything.
```

Even if you want to make changes to your code or html, leave the simulator open and make your code changes (and Save), and then click on Refresh button in simulator window to bring in your recent code changes without losing the database and its data. If you follow this approach you can easily test how a database would behave on  real device where a database is naturally persisted.

**So think, in terms of 'simulator session' when developing hybrid apps using Telerik AppBuilder.**